# Share data between CDI decorators

Tags: java, decorator, cdi

Is there the possibility to share data between two CDI decorators, which will invoked one after another?

In my case FirstDecorator calls a service and get back an id. SecondDecorator needs to know this id to call another service.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in context or anything like that that is shared between `Decorator`s.  There doesn't have to be.

Instead, you do this yourself.  Each `Decorator` would `@Inject` the same object that you would design, probably featuring a `setId()` method.  That is:

```
// In decorator 1:
@Inject
private IdHolder idHolder;

// In some method in decorator 1:
this.idHolder.setId(theIdInQuestion);

// In decorator 2:
@Inject
private IdHolder idHolder;

// In some method in decorator 2:
final Object id = this.idHolder.getId();

// The IdHolder class:
@ApplicationScoped // or some other scope that will "stick around" longer than @Dependent
class IdHolder {
  private Object id;
  Object getId() { return this.id; }
  void setId(final Object id) { this.id = id; }
}
```